# is it possible to bind a controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So it's possible to manually bootstrap a module to a chosen html element. But is it possible to do the similar thing with a controller? instead of using `ng-controller` directive, can you do it from javascript? Let's say your controller function code loads asynchronosly and on the `document.ready` it's not yet accessible, thus returns `undefined`. 
But is it possible to `ng-bind` it from the code, once the file with the controller function has loaded? I've tried to add a `ng-controller` attribute to an element from within javascript code, but of course it didn't work.

Comment: All controllers are just functions. How about you create a placeholder, a dummy controller before the real controller is load? And then replace it with the loaded controller? So it won't complain that it's undefined. Just a thought, no idea if that will work.

Comment: doesn't work that way :(

Comment: I need to find a way to lazy instantiation of controllers

Comment: As far as I am aware, it is not possible to lazy-load any code in AngularJS. What's your use case?

Comment: I could've told you but I have to quote Mark Zuckerberg instead: -"it's complicated"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $routeProvider to tell Angular what controller to load for a given view.  You do not need to use the ng-controller directive.

From the API reference:

```
$routeProvider.when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
    templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
    controller: ChapterCntl
});
```